# Is there anyway to set a binding on ALL scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind on scroll. Normally I would do this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', someFunction);
```

The issue is that I have a scroll bar on a specific div, so this doesn't work. I need to do this:

```
$('.divClass').bind('scroll', someFunction);
```

This works fine. I want to do this for ALL my scroll bars though. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `on()` method should typically be used instead of `bind()` in newer versions.

Comment: if I understand you right, you want to find out if something is scrolling and then bind some stuff on it? not only .divClass?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to scroll all scrollbars at the same times to be synchronized or you want to execute the function `someFunction` for all your div with a scrollbar when the div is scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Use on to bing all your div scrollbar, including the dynamically created div.

```
$(document).on('scroll','.divClass', someFunction);
```

The `.divClass` must be present on all your container where you want to execute the `someFunction` function.